# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters/ writing in txt file

Tags: python, unicode

i'm parcing a text file that has text in xml like configuration and the code i tried is this

```
file_handle_tester = open("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/talabat yarmook.txt","r", encoding="utf8")


sec_file = open("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/parced_text.txt","w")
a='com.talabat:id/textView_restaurantName'
menu = list()

for line in file_handle_tester:
    line = line.strip()
    menu.append(line)

for line in menu:
    sec_file.write(line)
```

python is not letting me print lines from the original file to the new file and i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\pyAppiumSandBox\venv\parcing_handle.py", line 14, in <module>
    sec_file.write(line)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 95-101: character maps to <undefined>
```

in the code above i tried to put the lines in a list because python has no problem with printing them on screen. the entire issue is when  writing them. but i still get the same error.

i tried opening the txt in byte format and decode it but that didn't work also

Comment: Change `sec_file = open("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/parced_text.txt","w")` to `sec_file = open("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/parced_text.txt","w", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: The default encoding is OS-dependent.  Always specify the encoding you want like you did on the `file_handle_tester`.  In this case you're on Windows and the default was `cp1252` and only supports a small subset of the millions of Unicode characters.  Your data has an unsupported character.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `sec_file = open("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/parced_text.txt","w")` to

`sec_file = open("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/parced_text.txt","w", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: pardon, i forgot to mention that i tried that too, but it also failed, the loop stumbles in one of the lines and gives the same error. I'm beginning to think it is because the file is xml code saved in a txt file (file_handle_tester)

Comment: sorry - if you get no errors  _Reading_ the source file as utf-8, you won't get errors writting the file as utf-8 (and would not get any error for any valid string) - this is the solution for the error you presented. You are likely getting a different error if you make this change. (Also, "utf-8" is not a charmap codec, so the error would not be the same).  And no, whatever the file represents as xml, or whatever has nothing to do with this error: you are interpreting it as text only.

Comment: (of course, your output file will simply contains all lines from the input file mingled together with no separation: once this works, it is hard to think the output is actually useful for anything)